# Creating a js file to be accessed by jsp

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

Alright heres the scenario. I'm creating a dynamic website with Java\JSP\JS. I'm using the Java to access a database and query a table to get information. Instead of passing that query to the JSP, I decided to create a JS file with a class in it with all of that information. (I'm basically building a store locator that will update itself with new stores\locations whenever the user presses a button. Obviously they need to update the table first but you get the point)

And now onto my problem. I'm creating the file by opening a stream. (But first I check to see if the file exists and if it does delete it, because I don't want to keep writing to that same file every time a user clicks the button.)

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("test.js");
```

The location of the file goes to my Eclipse folder directory, obviously. Even doing this,

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("./test.js");
```

put it there. Granted I didn't think it would change but I was testing it out.

The location of the JSP file when the project isn't 'deployed', or testing, its in the workspace location. But when it is 'deployed'

```
\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\BoomBaby\index.jsp
```

When I get the location of the JS file its:

```
/C:/Program%20Files/Apache/lib/
```

So my question, after all of this, is: How do I save the JS file in the same directory as the JSP file while deployed so I can access it from a JSP file by:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [build a WAR file](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/WebComponents3.html).  It is basically a zip file with a standardized layout.  You put all your jsps in one place, and all your js files in another.  Containers like tomcat understand the layout of the war and will run your application automatically.  Popular build tools like ant and maven will construct wars for you with little effort.

Comment: I know I can build a war file I just want to test out this code before I build anything. What I want to know is how to 'open'/'create' that file. Should I keep it how it is as `FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("test.js");`

Comment: no thats way to complicated.  The browser should get the resources for you.  You don't need to write code to stream them.  It would be better to deploy your first page normally, in a war, than to write code to do this.  Many IDEs will automatically create the correct project structure for you and allow you to run it from the IDE.

Comment: So all I need to do is export the project from eclipse as a war file and then deploy it on my tomcat server and then rewrite the code to be the correct directory.

Like if I deploy the code and the JSP file is in the directory 
`localhost:8080\blah\folder\index.jsp`

And the java file where the JS file is being created is in the directory
`localhost:8080\blah\folder2\MainBean.java`

I would just write the code to be
`FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("./folder/test.js");`

Or am I thinking about this too much and the project, regardless where the file is saved will know where it is?

Comment: Can you clarify for me? I'm kind of confused by that.

Comment: you should really follow a hello world WAR tutorial.

Comment: Yeah probably, in fact I am looking for some and I do want to learn. (I've only delt with WARs/Dynamic Java pages like once.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't when deployed as a WAR file.  The way this is usually done is, instead of generating a file and referring to it, *generate the JavaScript source into the page directly*.